# Visual Studio - Two copies running and prompted to reload project when nothing has changed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have two solution files:

- slnOne
- slnTwo

that both access the same projects:

- prjOne
- prjTwo

If I am working in slnOne and edit a .cs file contained within prjOne save it and then switch back to slnTwo I am prompted with "prjTwo.cproj has changed reload it...".

Now nothing has changed in prjTwo. I seem to recall there was a GUID that was set in the solution files somewhere that causes this, but I cannot find a reference to where I saw this (I think it was here on SO, but cannot be sure)

Can someone point me in the right direction? Because prjOne never suffers from this phantom reload prompt.

Comment: @Downvoter Good thing you left a comment as to why you were downvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue.

- Close down Visual Studio
- Open your solution file(s) and search for the section:

  Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "My.Application", "..\My.Application\MyApplication.csproj", "{B426B1C3-5ADA-4774-A810-3DEFA6994511}"
  EndProject

where **MyApplication.csproj** is the project you are having difficulties with. In each solution make sure that this section has the **same** trailing GUID. So in the above this is:

> {B426B1C3-5ADA-4774-A810-3DEFA6994511}

but yours will be different obviously. It does not matter which one you chose from your solution files, just make sure that it is consistent in all of them.